# Make Label(Floating Label) of TextInputLayout either Marquee or show in multiple lines

Tags: android, android-edittext, marquee, android-textinputlayout

I want to make label of `TextInputLayout` either Marquee or in Multiple lines.

I tried `android:ellipsize` property with `TextInputLayout` and with `AppCompatEditText` but not able to get desired result.

Please guide me how I can set Floating label of `TextInputLayout` either marquee or in multiple lines.

My code is as follows:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">


    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
        style="@style/style_name"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:hint="Demo Long Hint Text Text text Text Text Text"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:inputType="text" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

I also tried to apply `android:ellipsize="marquee" direct to EditText, but it causes crash my application.`

Comment: actually i am facing that props :(

Comment: https://github.com/IanGClifton/AndroidFloatLabel